# Error when i install openvpn

Tags: apt, dpkg

I got this error:

`apt-get install openvpn`

Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias

```
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt-get -f install» para corregirlo:
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 linux-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depende: linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 (= 4.13.0.36.55) pero 4.10.0.28.31 va a ser instalado
 openvpn : Depende: libpkcs11-helper1 (>= 1.11) pero no va a instalarse
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt-get -f install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
```

Something is wrong with my system. idk what is.

Comment: Did you tried `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: ofc not wrkin i tried and nothing

Comment: Try with `sudo`. And This is an English language website.

Comment: Just tried to install openvpn on system with HWE. No problem here. What is the output of `apt-cache policy linux-headers-generic-hwe-16.04 libpkcs11-helper1` (add output to question)?

Answer (score 0):

You need `libpkcs11-helper1` package so try to run following command before installing **openvpn**:

```
sudo apt-get install libpkcs11-helper1
```